# Can basis vectors contain more components than the dimension of the spanned vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, can I say $\left(1,0,1\right)$ and $\left(0,1,1\right)$ form the basis for a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: A basis vector doesn't contain any elements, so your title doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Also, your example takes vectors from ${\mathbb{R}^3}$ - so they cannot form a basis for ${\mathbb{R}^2}$

Comment: Also you list vectors that aren't members of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so no they can't form a basis.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments! I've edited my title and text. One more question @SeraPhim, how do you call the numbers in a vector, if not "elements"?

Comment: Elements are members of sets. Vectors aren't sets, and therefore don't contain elements. The numbers might be called components though.

Comment: @SeraPhim Thank you so much! I love to get all terminology right. I've edited my question. So, how do you think about the question? Can I say that?

Comment: Yeah what you've written is fine, although if I had to nitpick I would be wary of the phrase "spanning vector space", because it sort of implies that the vector space is doing the spanning, which isn't right; only vectors can span something. But I think I know what you're getting at so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @SeraPhim edited and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.  The dimension of the subspace (the plane) is $2$, but since it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, one must have $3$ components that describe the basis vectors which span it, or any other subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, and the editing!